# variable (form.onsubmit) still null after assignment

Tags: javascript

```
function registerForm(formName){
    if(!formName)
        return;
    var form = document[formName];

    form.onSubmit = function(){
        console.log('I am the onsubmit function');
    };
    console.log('onsubmit set: ' + form.onsubmit);
}


window.onload = function(){

    registerForm('myform');

};
```

This is a snippet of a larger section of code.

As you can see, I am assigning form.onsubmit to equal an anonymous function

However, the assignment does not work.

Replacing the assignment with form.onsubmit = 1 does not work either - the value is still null afterwards.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is case sensitive. `onSubmit` is not `onsubmit`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8sQPK/)

And you should use `onsubmit`.